# How do I find all ingress in K8S that have not received a request?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I use nginx ingress.

If ingress has not received a request, there is no record of the ingress in Prometheus, so one idea I came up with was to list all the ingress names and query Prometheus. If there is no record of the ingress, there is no request to access this host. However, this performance is too low, is there a better way?

Comment: please clarify the request, not sure to understand what you tried or want to accomplish. but if it is just about listing the ingress service in, your kubernetes cluster you should play with the commande kubectl get : kubectl get ingress, more here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: @AitZaid I want to know if the ingress received an HTTP request

Comment: ok well start by providing context , do a describe ofg your ingress and folow some steps to provide it here in your question : you can look in this website https://medium.com/@theodorahcheng/kubernetes-ingress-101-troubleshooting-ingress-5f2be086cca3

Comment: your issue has been fixed or not?